# Comparing model fit with heteroscedastic data

Tags: correlation, heteroscedasticity, distance, model-comparison

I am developing a physiological test using R that requires some parameters optimised.  In comparing the new method against the existing method, the values of individual readings correlate in a linear way but are very heteroscedastic - the variance approximately proportional to the mean.

I would like to compare the effects of various parameter changes by examining the goodness-of-fit of the linear models compared with each other.  Confidence intervals around the linear model parameters are not needed. Comparing  R squareds does not seem appropriate given the heteroscedasticity.  Would distance correlation or R squared after HCCM correction be appropriate ways to test if one method is superior to another ?

Comment: So to confirm, you are asking about how to compare model fit when the models compared have heteroscedastic errors?

Comment: yes - were it not for the heteroscedasticity I would be comparing r squareds or correlation coefficients